# Joint Distribution from marginal distributions and the distribution of the sum

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Let's assume I know the marginal distributions of two random variables.

Does knowing the marginal distribution of their sum or their linear combination in general gives me any information on the possible joint distribution? Can it improve the Frechet bounds for the joint?

Is it possible to have general results without imposing restrictions on the type of the marginal distributions?